# Using an online tool to generate a random name

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I found this website http://www.mess.be/inickgenwuname.php

It allows you to type in a name and it will generate a random rapper name. I wanted to have a button on my website that just generates the name for you so I decided to write some javascript that will send a request to this website and parse the response to get the random name.

Here is the node.js code I wrote.

```
function getRandomName() {
    var http = require('http');
    var data = {
   realname:"something"
};
var querystring = require("querystring");
var qs = querystring.stringify(data);
var qslength = qs.length;
var options = {
    hostname: "www.mess.be",
    path: "/inickgenwuname.php",
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': qslength
    }
};

var str = "";
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
       str+=chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        var s = str.slice(str.indexOf("From this day forward, I will be known as... ") + "From this day forward, I will be known as... ".length,
            str.indexOf("-And you"));
        s = s.replace("\n", "").trim();
        console.log(s);
    });
});

req.write(qs);
req.end();
}
```

When I went to the website and pressed f12 on chrome and inspected the code, I found this little segment...

[image]

So this is what I used to formulate the request to the php. However, I only guessed through trial and error that the data that needed to be send was key-value pair object where the key is `realname`. My question is, how would I have known this otherwise? Is there no way to find out from the website, where the data being send with the POST is being received from?

Comment: you can probably just run the cgi a dozen or two times to get the adjective and nouns, then roll the dice yourself without any network usage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why by guessing? The form tells you everything that needs to be sent.

Also you could press F12 -> Network, and then send the request. After this you look at the sent requests and search for a POST request. When you click on the `/inickgenwuname.php` request you get more information about it. In there you can see Response Headers / Request Headers and as a last category "Form Data". There you can see all the data that is sent with this form.

I hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing bandwidth without proper compensation (so called web-scraping) is quite commonly frowned upon. I couldn't find anything on that site that allows for it although I did not search thoroughly.

Why don't you roll your own? It's *very* simple, as can be seen in this Q&D hack:

```
function wu_names(input){
  // some nice, fitting adjectives. Add more
  var adjectives = ["annoying", "crazy", "expert", "insane", "lucky", "sardonic", "pestering"];
  // some nice, fitting nouns. Add more
  var nouns = ["assassin", "bastard", "conjurer", "destroyer", "ninja", "prophet", "wizard"];
  var first = "";
  var second = "";
  var hash = 0;
  var primitive_hash = function(s){
    var h = 0;
    for(var i = 0;i < s.length;i++){
      var c = s.charCodeAt(i);
      // standard hash = hash * 31 + c
      h = ((h << 5) - h>>>0) + c;
    }
    return h;
  };

  first = input.split(" ")[0];
  // no useful entry at all
  if(first === undefined){
    return null;
  }
  hash = primitive_hash(first);
  first = adjectives[hash % adjectives.length];
  second = input.split(" ")[1];
  // no second entry
  if(second === undefined){
    return null;
  }
  hash = primitive_hash(second);
  second = nouns[hash % nouns.length];

  return first + " " + second;
}
```

The lists of adjectives and nouns is quite short, you might add to them, as the comments suggest.

Comment: I didn't occur to me that what I'm doing is not right. I'm new to front end development. I guess I will just make my own one, eventhough my rapper names might not be as good

Comment: Well, CPUs are cheap and hardrives with several terabytes of capacity get offered for little money, but bandwidth is still relatively expensive in contrast. And as I said: I haven't checked the whole site, they might allow for it. BTW: the original seems to be very old, found one example from 2000 here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/alt.tv.x-files/FHrjy96LuiA#!topic/alt.tv.x-files/FHrjy96LuiA